# Show content from subfolder but with root URL

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

So the website https://smartminds.io/ should fetch the content from https://smartminds.io/staging but should have URL as https://smartminds.io/

This is running on wordpress so how can I achieve this.

Comment: Is your WP installation located in `staging` folder?

Comment: It is both on Staging and live, but the think is staging has better site performance when I move staging to Live the performance and cache plugins are getting conflicts

Answer (score -1):

Hi below are the steps for achieving this

1) Log in to the Dashboard of your WordPress site

2) Go to Settings / General and change the Site Address (URL) to your root, in your case : https://smartminds.io/

This will automatically change the .htaccess file on the server.

3) Open up your FTP Client or navigate to files using your web host’s file management tool. Copy (IMPORTANT: COPY, DON’T MOVE) the files .htaccess and index.php into your root directory.

4) Open up index.php and make sure the line at the bottom that reads: require(‘staging/wp-blog-header.php’); is pointing to the directory where your blog actually lives (in this case, the directory is ‘staging’).

Upload the files to the root directory. And that’s it.

Comment: Is it? sorry for that. I thought your root directory is not live now.

Comment: No its ok, My wesbite is live now I want the data to be fetched from staging